# Convert string representing a number of any base to number

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I need to decode base36 string to double. The actual double value is **0.3128540377812142**. Now when I am converting it to base 36:

```
(0.3128540377812142).toString(36);
```

Results are :

```
Chrome: 0.b9ginb6s73gd1bfel7npv0wwmi
Firefox: 0.b9ginb6s73e
```

Now my question is:

1) Is there any way to get same base 36 result for all browsers ?

2) How to decode them back to double value ?

Comment: I don't believe the extra digits out of Chrome are really significant.

Comment: 1) write your own function. ES6 says about Number.prototype.toString: "[The precise algorithm is implementation-dependent](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-number.prototype.tostring)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For converting from string (up to base 36) to a number you can use this.

```
String.prototype.toNumber = function(base) {
    var resultNumber = 0;
    var inMantissa = false;
    var mantissaDivisor;
    var currentCharCode;
    var digitValue;

    if (typeof base === "undefined" || base === "" || base === null) {
        base = 10;
    }
    base = parseInt(base);
    if (isNaN(base) || base > 36 || base < 2) {
        return NaN;
    }


    for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
        currentCharCode = this.charCodeAt(i);
        if (currentCharCode === 46 && !inMantissa) {
            // we're at the decimal point
            inMantissa = true;
            mantissaDivisor = 1;
        } else {
            if (currentCharCode >= 48 && currentCharCode <= 57) {
                // 0-9
                digitValue = currentCharCode - 48;
            } else if (currentCharCode >= 65 && currentCharCode <= 90) {
                // A-Z
                digitValue = currentCharCode - 55;
            } else if (currentCharCode >= 97 && currentCharCode <= 122) {
                // a-z
                digitValue = currentCharCode - 87;
            } else {
                return NaN;
            }

            if (digitValue > base - 1) {
                return NaN;
            }
            if (inMantissa) {
                mantissaDivisor *= base;
                resultNumber += digitValue/mantissaDivisor;
            } else {
                resultNumber = (resultNumber * base) + digitValue;
            }
        }
    }
    return resultNumber;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ugshkp4d/25/

Comment: Stupid and slightly off topic question, but is the `(typeof base === "undefined" || base === "" || base === null)` really necessary? Are there circumstances where `base==null` isn't enough to detect the absence of a parameter? This one also accepts `toNumber([36])` as OK.

Comment: @MrLister, your first two questions there would make a really good question to post here on SO. It'd be interesting to get community feedback on that. Regarding the acceptance of non-`number`s, I made a change; thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I didn't mean `base==null` as the only error checking, only as a good enough means to detect empty parameters, as in `toNumber()`. Which is not the same as `toNumber('')`. The latter can trigger an error if you like.